# Custom LSTM model in Pytorch showing input size mismatch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a custom bidirectional LSTM model where the custom part is

```
- extract the forward and backward last hidden state
- concat those states
- create a fully connected layer and pass it through softmax layer.
```

The code looks like below:

```
class customModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(customModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.bilstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=False, bidirectional=True)
        self.fcl = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Set initial hidden and cell states 
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)

        # Forward propagate LSTM
        out, hidden = self.bilstm(x, (h0, c0))  # out: tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_size)
        #concat hidden state of forward and backword
        fw_bilstm = out[-1, :, :self.hidden_size]
        bk_bilstm = out[0, :, :self.hidden_size]
        concat_fw_bw = torch.cat((fw_bilstm, bk_bilstm), dim = 1)
        fc = nn.Linear(concat_fw_bw, num_classes)
        x = F.relu(fc(x))
        return F.softmax(x)
```

I use below parameters and input

```
input_size = 2
hidden_size = 32  
num_layers = 1
num_classes = 2

input_embedding = [
    torch.FloatTensor([[-0.8264],  [0.2524]]),
    torch.FloatTensor([[-0.3259],  [0.3564]])
]
```

Then I create a model object

```
model = customModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes)
```

Which then I use like below:

```
for item in input_embedding:
    print(item.size())
    for epoch in range(1):  
        pred = model(item)  
        print (pred)
```

When I run it, I see for this line `out, hidden = self.bilstm(x, (h0, c0))`, it shows error

```
RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2
```

I am not sure why the model is thinking that input must have 3 dimensions when I explicitly specified `input_size=2`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a (*batch* or *sequence*) dimension in your input.

There is a difference between [`nn.LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm) and [`nn.LSTMCell`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstmcell). The former -- which is the one you use -- takes whole sequences as inputs. Therefore it needs 3-dimensional inputs of shape (seq_len, batch, input_size).

Let's say you want to give those 4 sequences of letters (which you code as one-hot vectors) as inputs in form of a batch:

```
x0 = [a,b,c]
x1 = [c,d,e]
x2 = [e,f,g]
x3 = [h,i,j]

### input.size() should give you the following:
(3,4,8)
```

- The `seq_len` parameter is the size of the sequences: here 3,
- The `input_size` parameter is the size of each input vector: here, the input would be a one-hot vector of size 8,
- The `batch` is the number of sequences you put together: here there are 4 sequences.

NB: It can be easier to grasp by putting the batch sequence first and setting the `batch_first` as True

Also: if (h_0, c_0) is not provided, both h_0 and c_0 default to zero so it's not useful to create them.